# How to pass enum as argument in ctypes python?

Tags: python, enums, ctypes

I have a `dll` and a `c` header file `.h`. There are some functions which accepts `c` `enum`, for example;

```
enum Type
{
    typeA,
    typeB
};
```

and a function

```
bool printType(Type type );
```

Now I want to use this function of `dll` from a python script. I have imported the library. It is successful. I can access other functions and it works. So there is one funciton like I gave example above which takes an `Enum` as parameter.

What I have tried after looking into other posts here and other stuff on internet;

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from ctypes import *
from enum import IntEnum

class CtypesEnum(IntEnum):
    @classmethod
    def from_param(cls, obj):
        return int(obj)

class Type(CtypesEnum):
    typeA     = 0
    typeB     = 1
```

I have used it like this.

```
setEnumtype = self.printType
setEnumtype.argtypes = [Type]
setEnumVale.restype = c.c_int
result = self.printType(setEnumtype.typeA)
```

Interpreter says, it does know `IntEnum`. I have installed `enum` by pip.

Is there another and straightforward way to do this?

Traceback:

```
from enum import IntEnum
ImportError: cannot Import Name IntEnum
```

Comment: please post the *exact* traceback (i.e. copy and paste the text)

Comment: I have posted the original traceback.

Answer (score 1):

If you read [the enum docs on pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum/0.4.6) you'll see:

> Python 3 now has in its standard library an enum implementation (also available for older Python versions as the third-party flufl.enum distribution) that supersedes this library.

You actually want [enum34](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34).

Comment: attributeError: Instancmethod object has not atrribute type `argtypes`

Comment: @GulluButt you might want to update your question with your code that is producing this error